# Having trouble with basic Binary Search

Tags: search, binary

That is my code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int number = 12;
  boolean result;


  int [] array = {2,4,6,8,10};
  result = calculateNumber(array, number, array.length-1);

  System.out.println("The result is " + result);
}

public static boolean calculateNumber(int [] array, int number, int max) {
  int min = 0;
  int mid = 0;
  boolean result = false;

  while (min <= max) {
    mid = min + max / 2;

    if (number > array[mid]) {
      min = mid + 1;
    }
    if (number < array[mid]) {
      max = mid - 1;
    }
    else if (number == array[mid]) {
      return result = true;
    }
  }

  return result;

}
}
```

As you can see, i'm trying to find if the number 12 is in the array. It's not, so it's supposed to return "false", but i'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
```

I know what it means but i don't understand why i get it..
I've traced my code a bunch of times and couldn't find a solution..
When i tried to check for the numbers 2,4,6, it worked perfectly. For any other number like 8, 10, or greater, it crashes. 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems simple enough. If your array has 10 elements in it, the last valid index is 9.

Yet, your code calculates an index that is too high. Lets assume max is 10.
You then calculate mid as 10+(10/2) = 15. (the divide takes precedence over the add)

I'd change make a couple of changes and try again.

1. Change your terminating condition. `while (min <= max)` to `while (min < max)`
2. Be explicit with your equation, use brackets. `mid = (min+max) / 2`

Comment: Perfect!

Apparently the problem was i didn't put min+max in parenthesis, so it was dividing max by 2, and THEN adding them together.

That's embarrassing..

Many thanks!!!